# R Mutate Column Query

Tags: r

I am stuck in an Intresting Problem.

I have this dataset

```
CARD_NO(char),Name(char), Amount(integer), Date(Date)   
6323246954,Ramon Lopez,62472.07,2019-01-02
7021289247,Bruce Yael,26245.30,2018-12-14
8311285536,Daisy Pascal,42377.31,2018-12-23
8541521746,Amy Chris,107978,2018-12-19
```

For each row of the dataset I have to add a new column which should be a string of length 10 .
The Rules of generating the String is as Follows

```
V1 : ="S" if amount is >50000 else "F"
V2,V4,V6,V8,V10 : Reverse of (99999-first five digits of the CARD_NO.)

eg. for second row CARD_NO = 7021289247
First 5 digits= 70212
99999-70212= 29787
Reverse(29787) : 78792
therefore V2 =7
V4=8
V6=7
V8=9
V10:=2


now to calculate other
V3: If First letter of First name is at Nth position in alphabetical order, find alphabet in Nth position of reverse alphabetical order. 
V5: If First letter of Last name is at Nth position in alphabetical order, find alphabet in Nth position of reverse alphabetical order.
V7: single digit sum of Amount 
V9: single digit sum of Date 


eg: 2nd row 
7021289247,Bruce Yael,26245.30,2018-12-14
V3 = "Y" as firstname_firstchar="B" i.e at index 2 therefore Y (index 2 from reverse side)
V5="B" as lastname_firstchar="Y" i.e at index 25 therefore B (index 25 from reverse side)
V7=4 as amount =26245.30 
therefore 2+6+2+4+5+3+0 =22 -> 2+2 =4

V9=1 as date = 2018-12-14
2+0+1+8+1+2+1+4 =19 -> 1+9=10 -> 1+0 =1

also V1="F" as amount is Less than 50000
```

so finally 
 for 7021289247, Bruce Yael,26245.30,2018-12-14

the generated String is **F7Y8B74912**

Please help me write a R code to create this new Column for all the Rows based on these rules

Comment: hi Madridista, the way things tend to work here is that you must first try coding this yourself. Then, we can help you fix the code if it doesn't work. Please also read [the Help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: I have tried.. but my approach is very bad and time consuming .. i here just want to know the alog

Comment: Before you ask a question, make sure your question is correct. why 99999-63232 = 29787? do u mean 99999-70212?

Comment: corrected it ..sorry